# Change cell colour if cell date is due to expire within a set time period

Tags: excel, vba, date, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Im trying to build a training matrix that will have a breakdown of all the training staff require, when it was completed and when its due to be renewed. The training is due every 3 years from its initial completion so what i want to do is have cells turn red if its been over 3 years, turn amber  if its due renewel within 2 months and green if needs renewing in more than 2 months of the date in the cell.

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out so thank you in advance to who ever saves me.

I've tried using conditional formatting 3 colour scales and other formulas ive found on google but none that work from the date in the cell specifically.

I have tried:

```vb
Sub CheckDateAndFormat()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("C5:C20")
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value >= DateAdd("yyyy", -3, Date) And cell.Value <= DateAdd("yyyy", 3, Date) Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Formula wise I tried:

```
=AND(C6>TODAY(), C6-TODAY()<=1095)
```

which will highlight it green when its within 3 years but once its close to expiring or expired it doesn't change its colour.

I have attached a link to the picture of what I would like it to look like in regard to the training layout.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq4Cd.png

Comment: Please provide example

Comment: Please share your attempt (formula) and a screenshot of the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(TODAY()-`Cell Number of Date Completed ex. B3`>1095, TRUE, FALSE)
```

You can then apply [conditional formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-conditionally-format-text-c983d661-07b6-4932-8725-b682c4f77ce1) to make the color change accordingly - Red for True, Green for False, and Amber if it's false, but the difference between the date of training and today is less then 60 days (2 months)